# junit5 test case for a method which returns nothing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I have the below method, but I am not able to create a test case for this. Can you please help ?

I dont want to use Mocking.

```java
class A {
    public void setValue(PersonInfo a, Person b){
        if (a.getFullname() == null) {
            b.setFullName(a.getFirstName());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see if I set a value for `PersonInfo.firstname` then whether it's setting as the full name of the Person or not.

Tried the below approach but it's coming as null

```
class TestClasss{

  @Autowired
  A a;
  public void TestValue(){
    Person p = new Person();
    PersonInfo pi= new PersonInfo();
    pi.setFirstName("TEST");

    a.setValue(pi,p);
  
    assertEqual("TEST",p.getFullName());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below.

```
@Test
public void testA(){
  A ao = new A();
  PersonInfo a = new PersonInfo();
  a.setFirstName("Name");
  Person b = new Person();
  //call you method here
  ao.setValue(a, b);
  // As values of b object changed in the method so it will be reflected after 
  // method call also 
  // simple assertion... based on your requirement update this assert statement
  Assert.equals(a.getFirstName(), b.getFullName()); 
}
```

I also tried with same example .. I am getting values.
I have attached one screenshot you can also verify.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have also followed the same approach, but getting the value as null

Comment: @raj Please check the screenshot. I have added from my local system.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would write a couple tests:

- Test 1: Create a `PersonInfo` with a `null` full name, and a `Person` with a known full name that's different from the `PersonInfo` first name. Assert that the `Person` full name equals the `PersonInfo` first name.
- Test 2: Create a `PersonInfo` with a non-null full name, and a Person with a known full name that's different from the `PersonInfo` first name. Save the `Person`full name in a variable. Assert that the `Person` full name is different from the `PersonInfo` first name and equal to the value of the variable in which you saved it.

Comment: the problem is how you will access the the values from those two objects ? I am getting null values while trying to compate the value with expected and actual

Comment: Well, how have you created those objects? Have you set values for their properties? The code you posted doesn't show that.

Comment: I have added that part. please refresh.

Comment: Post the `Person` and `PersonInfo` classes, we need to know what their constructors do.

Comment: they have PersonInfo has default and Person has a default constructor which is creating two arraylists

Comment: The only reason why in your test the full name of your `Person` would not be TEST is if your `PersonInfo` has a `null` full name.

Comment: yes, I am making as null so that it satisfy the condition

Comment: I meant a non-null full name, not null. If you are making it null, then it's impossible that, if your code is exactly as you've shown us, the test fails because `Person.fullname` is null.